# Highlight list data from database in Calender VIew Event

Tags: java, android, sql, calendarview

I have some data in my database, a date format and I want to display in the calendar event a highlight, but only 1 data is highlighted, how can I highlight all the data..?

```
     try {
          String query = "Select * from dsewa order by TGLBUKTI asc";
          Log.e("fifala",""+query);
          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

          List<Calendar> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
          Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

          while (rs.next()) {
              bukti = rs.getString("TGLBUKTI");

              c.setTime(sdf.parse(bukti));
              Log.e("rara",""+c.getTime());
              calendars.add(c);
              Log.e("sara",""+c.getTime());
              Log.e("kara",""+bukti);
          }

          if(!rs.next())
          {
              //ketika semua list udah di tambah, tampilin disini
              calendarView.setHighlightedDays(calendars);

              Log.e("kevin",""+calendars.size());
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("error", "" + e .getMessage());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `calendarView` is, exactly, but you need to move the `Calendar` instantiation into the loop; e.g., move the `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();` line to right before the `c.setTime()` line. As you have it now, you're just modifying and adding the same `Calendar` object repeatedly.

Comment: okeee thank you mike , this workkkk , thank youuu